# How to hide friends I have already added as friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code. Adding friend part works well. But afterward I still see the "Add friend" button. So I added <% if... part, but @friendship rendered error (controller code below), so I added <% @friendships.each do... part. Still doesn't work; many "Add friend" on each user show.

```rb
<% @friendships.each do |friendship|%>
  <% if current_user.id != friendship.user_id and post.book.user_id != friendship.friend_id %>
    <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => post.book.user_id), :method => :post %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```rb
@friendship = Friendship.where(friend_id: params[:user_id])
@friendships = Friendship.all
```

How can I fix this? Would it be better to undo the migration and install has_friendship gem (undo, because both the gem and my current implementation use "Friendship" model)?

Friendship model:

```rb
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand problem: 'many "Add friend" on each user show.'
So, you have user show page and let it be @user variable.

```
<% if !current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: @user.id).exists? %>
  <button>Add Friend</button>
<% end %>
```

`exists?` method is more efficient than other methods. If you are on special user page you don't need getting all friends.

Also, just to be clear

```
@friendships = Friendship.all
```

Will load all friends of all users, not just for current user.

Also, with this implementation you need to ensure that adding a friend is symmetrical, after adding a friend table must have 2 rows

```
| user_id | friend_id |
|       1 |.        2 |
|.      2 |.        1 |
```

Otherwise your friend could not know that he is your friend. I suggest to index both columns.

About has_friendship gem: didn't use, but I believe that custom code in such situation will be more flexible and easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

As written it looks like you are looping through every friendship that exists in your database. You only need to loop through the friends of the current user.

Not only will that be a much smaller list, but every member of that list will already be a friend and you won't have to ask whether or not an "Add Friend" link should be displayed.

Consider the following.

First, we restate the models in a slightly different way:

```rb
class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connections
  has_many :friends, through: :connections, class_name: "User"
end
```

Next, we make some users:

```rb
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> ['User One', 'User Two', 'User Three' ].each { |u| User.create(name: u) }
...
=> ["User One", "User Two", "User Three"]
irb(main):002:0> users = User.all
...
irb(main):003:0> users.size
...
=> 3
irb(main):004:0>
```

Then, we connect some users:

```rb
irb(main):004:0> Connection.create(user: User.first,  friend: User.second)
irb(main):005:0> Connection.create(user: User.second, friend: User.first)
irb(main):006:0> Connection.create(user: User.second, friend: User.third)
irb(main):007:0> Connection.create(user: User.third,  friend: User.second)
```

Now, we can display the friends of a particular user like this:

```rb
<% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
  <% friend.name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```